# Deshabilitar la orientacion horizontal para smartphones pero permitida en tabletas para Android

Tags: android, kotlin

Necesito deshabilitar la orientación horizontal en las vistas donde corre sobre un smarphone pero permitir a las tabletas que pueda rotar la vista.

Tengo lo siguiente:
en AndroidManifest

```xml
<activity android:name=".SomeActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="locked" />
```

y en cada activity cargo eso

```kotlin
    int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation
    if (isTablet()) {   
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR)
    } else if(orientation != Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {   
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
    }
```

Funciona bien, excepto si mi app está en segundo plano, y se viene de una app en modo horizontal al volver a mi app pues permite su orientación horizontal, cuando deberia setearse en vertical.

Alguna otra opción de bloquear la orientación en vertical si corre en un smartphone pero permitir orientación vertical y horizontal si corre en una tablet.

Comment: [Forzar orientacion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067426/android-force-horizontal-landscape-layout)
Aqui una posible solucion, intenta echarle un ojo ya que es la misma pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solventado:

antes de establecer `locked` poner `portrait`

```xml
<activity android:name=".SomeActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

y l uego en cada actividad que se requiere que en tabletas se pueda rotar la pantalla

```kotlin
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView...
    this.setPortraitSmartphone()
```

**Extesion fuctions**

```kotlin
fun Context.isTablet(): Boolean {
    val xlarge = resources.configuration.screenLayout and Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE
    val large =
        resources.configuration.screenLayout and Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE
    return xlarge || large
}

@SuppressLint("SourceLockedOrientationActivity")
fun Activity.setPortraitSmartphone() {
    val isTablet = this.isTablet()//resources.getBoolean(R.bool.isTablet)
    val orientation = resources.configuration.orientation
    if (isTablet) {
        this.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR
    } else if (orientation != Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        this.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
    }
}
```

Para el layout que solo se muestre horizontal en tabletas ponerlo en
`layout-w600-land`